# How do I control the order for iteration of a dictionary created from plist items?

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, plist, nsdictionary

How do I control the order for iteration of a dictionary, or items from a plist?

I have a plist with 65 items. Each item is a dictionary with three items, a number (index), and two strings that are names of images. the plist looks like this:

```
<key>Item 1</key>
<dict>
    <key>index</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>thumb</key>
    <string>001_item01.png</string>
    <key>pdf</key>
    <string>001_item01</string>
</dict>
<key>Item 2</key>
<dict>
    <key>index</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>thumb</key>
    <string>002_item02.png</string>
    <key>pdf</key>
    <string>002_item02</string>
</dict>
```

and so on...

I can build a dictionary from the plist as below, but I have not figured out how to determine the order. I need to pull each item in order according to the item number or index.

```
NSDictionary * myDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Items" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

In fact when I iterate, the order is random seemingly:

```
for(id key in myDict)
    NSLog(@"key=%@ value=%@", key, [myDict objectForKey:key]);


2013-04-27 18:12:52.576 dicTest[47865:c07] 007_item07.png
2013-04-27 18:12:52.577 dicTest[47865:c07] 052_item52.png
2013-04-27 18:12:52.577 dicTest[47865:c07] 045_item45.png
2013-04-27 18:12:52.577 dicTest[47865:c07] 038_item38.png
2013-04-27 18:12:52.578 dicTest[47865:c07] 010_item10.png
2013-04-27 18:12:52.578 dicTest[47865:c07] 008_item08.png
2013-04-27 18:12:52.578 dicTest[47865:c07] 046_item46.png
2013-04-27 18:12:52.579 dicTest[47865:c07] 009_item09.png
```

trying to grab items (dictionaries) in order based on index:

```
    NSDictionary * dictionary = [myDict objectForKey:[myDict.allKeys objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are explicitly and necessarily unordered.

If you want a specific order, you must use a container that supports the ordering of its contents, such as an array.

What you likely want to do is to change the outer container in your plist to an array, get rid of the index field, and replace it with a name or id field, containing what is now the keys of the dictionary.

Alternatively, you could keep the file as is, and create a secondary array to allow accessing elements by index, rather than by key.

(Usually, tho', if you're iterating over something, that something should likely be an array, and not a dictionary, although that's not a hard rule.)

---

**As for accessing object by their index field:**

This bit is a bit obscure, but simple enough to do:

One option is this:

```
NSArray *myIndex = [[myDict allValues] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
  return [[obj1 valueForKey:@"index"] compare:[obj2 valueForKey:@"index"]];
}];
```

This assumes that the resulting array would be dense; i.e. that all indexes are present, without gaps.

Comment: Thanks, yes I get it. I think I can easily figure out how to implement your first suggestion, which is good,  but I was trying to figure out how to use the index item of each sub-dictionary item to determine order. Is there a simple way to explain that? See very the bottom of my question for the code I am using, but is apparently not working.

Comment: sortedArrayUsingComparator

Comment: @Mrwolfy: Right you are. I still wouldn't really recommend that particular approach in this case, but it's an option.

Comment: OK thanks, yea, seems more complex than the array method, so I'll probably go with that, but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified example of using `sortedArrayUsingComparator` for reference.

```
NSArray *someArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@1,@3,@6,@8,@5,@2,@4,@7, nil];
NSArray *sortedArray = [someArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [obj1 compare:obj2];
}];

//log the sorted array
    for (NSNumber *num in sortedArray) {
        NSLog(@"%@", num);
    }
```